# How to give color to polygon border in leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, tile-layer

I am using geojson-vt for genreating polygon on leaflet map.polygon which is genreated is having some color...here i want to give different color to polygon border ...below is my geojson

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              74.276821428571402,
              20.089249999999982
            ],
            [
              74.267821428571402,
              20.089249999999982
            ],
            [
              74.267821428571402,
              20.098249999999982
            ],
            [
              74.276821428571402,
              20.098249999999982
            ],
            [
              74.276821428571402,
              20.089249999999982
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      },
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "description": "This is crop value",
        "color":"#ffb6c1",
        "pixel": {
          "latitude": 20.093749999999982,
          "vci": 2,
          "longitude": 74.272321428571402
        }
      }
    }
```

what changes should i do to genreate polygon with different border color.

am using leaflet to display polygon and geojson vt for drawing the polygon

```
       tileIndex = geojsonvt(data, tileOptions);




    tileLayer = L.canvasTiles()
                  .params({ debug: false, padding: 5 })
                  .drawing(drawingOnCanvas)


    var pad = 0;


tileLayer.addTo(leafletMap);
```

Comment: You have tagged your question both leaflet and mapbox-gl-js. What libary are you actually trying to display the polygon in?

Comment: i m using leaflet

Comment: i have updated my code

Comment: Do you expect the polygon to be styled using the properties of your GeoJSON feature? If not, the answer @Bill-chappel provided should work

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you style a polygon you can have the border one color and the fill another.

```
function polystyle(feature) {
    return {
        fillColor: 'blue',
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',  //Outline color
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    };
}

L.geoJson(polyData, {style: polystyle}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: so here border color will be white and polygon color will be blue

Comment: i have updated my code....when i try how to apply style when m using tilelayer like this  tileLayer.addTo(leafletMap);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547088/how-to-display-vector-tiles-generated-by-geojson-vt-in-leaflet has a code example that may help.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/sumbera/c67e5551b21c68dc8299  this may be a better example.

Comment: You can simplify the style this way.

var polystyle = {
        fillColor: 'blue',
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',  //Outline color
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    }

Answer (score 2):

For different style in each feature in Geojson file, I copied from [ThomazicM's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/330965/139465):

```
function setStyle(feature) {
  return {
    fillColor: feature.properties.fillColor,
    color: feature.properties.strokeColor,
    fillOpacity: feature.properties.fillOpacity,
    opacity: feature.properties.strokeOpacity
  };
}
```

and then call this function like

```
L.geoJson("polyData.geojson", {style: setStyle}).addTo(map);
```